# Create filter in Gmail inbox

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I wanted to create a filter in Gmail such that the message from specific person goes into my own made labels. Google already have some own labels. and I have also made my own labels but messages does not go into those labels.[image: my own made labels but box always remains empty]
[image]

Comment: You appear to be using a smartphone app. You can only create filters from the web app. (Smartphone apps are also off-topic here.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the smartphone version of an app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open Gmail.
2. In the search box at the top, click the Down arrow .
3. Enter your search criteria. If you want to check that your search worked correctly, see what emails show up by clicking Search .
4. At the bottom of the search window, click Create filter with this search.
5. Choose what you’d like the filter to do.
6. Click Create filter.
7. When you create a filter to forward messages, only new messages will be affected.

Reference: [Create rules to filter your emails](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en)

[image: Gmail Filters]